# What does an SQLite 'Error binding parameter 0: probably unsupported type' mean?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-db-api

I have Python code:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (email, password, password_hint, state, last_saved) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, DATETIME("now"));',
((get_cgi('email'),), (password,), (get_cgi('password_hint'),), (get_cgi('current'),)))
```

This is generating the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_account.cgi", line 73, in <module>
    ((get_cgi('email'),), (password,), (get_cgi('password_hint'),), (get_cgi('current'),)))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

A debug log of get_cgi('email') placed just before the crash returns the expected email address, so I would expect that the column 'email' of type TEXT should be able to deal with it.

What is SQLite3 complaining about? Have I missed some detail of DB-API2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're creating all those nested tuples, but removing them should make things work better; a tuple is not supported to insert (at least in this way) into a text field.

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO users (email, password, password_hint, state, last_saved) ' +
    'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, DATETIME("now"));',
    (get_cgi('email'), password, get_cgi('password_hint'), get_cgi('current')))
```

Comment: Thank you; it's working now. I thought other DB-API2 documentation said to give tuples, not non-container types or strings.

Comment: @JonathanHayward All parameters should be in the same tuple, that's why the `()` are surrounding all of them together.